# Can I remove the JSON-LD schema that Yoast adds to my WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, seo, schema.org, json-ld

I would like to remove the JSON-LD schema that Yoast applies to my WordPress site so that I can add my own.  I have already added my own, and Google Structured Data Testing says that it is OK, but basically I have 3 separate JSON-LD schemas instead of two because of Yoast.

You can see what I mean here: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yogabearpc.com

Yoast has added the `WebSite` schema and it seems unnecessary or even damaging?

Answer (score 9):

I wanted to disable this because of the sitelinks searchbox and the fact that I don't have a search function that works globally, just on the blog. Having the search box enabled for me would have undesirable effects.

The easier option may just be to prevent Google using the sitelinks searchbox without having to touch the functions files. You can prevent Google using sitelinks searchbox on your site by using the following meta:

```
<meta name="google" content="nositelinkssearchbox" />
```

If you want to disable Yoast's JSON-LD all together then here's a snippet from my blog and the code I use on my site:

> [SOURCE](https://www.bybe.net/yoast-seo-guide-disable-schema-json-ld-wordpress/)
>
> #### How to disable Yoast SEO Schema JSON-LD completely
>
> ```
> function bybe_remove_yoast_json($data){
>   $data = array();
>   return $data;
> }
> add_filter('wpseo_json_ld_output', 'bybe_remove_yoast_json', 10, 1);
> ```
>
> Login to your WordPress dashboard and head over to the editor
>   within the tab menu appearance, find your functions file (normally
>   named functions.php) and add the code below just before the PHP tag is
>   closed at the bottom.

Comment: How can i disable Yoast SEO Schema JSON-LD only in woocommerce's product category page and shop page?

Answer (score 5):

**Simplest way to completely disable the Yoast SEO schema JSON-LD**

Add this line to `functions.php file`:

`add_filter( 'wpseo_json_ld_output', '__return_empty_array' );`

[Source](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/2536#issuecomment-112553038)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable just *Organization* or just *Website*, add this to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function bybe_remove_yoast_json($data){
    if ( (isset($data['@type'])) && ($data['@type'] == 'Organization') ) {
        $data = array();
    }
    return $data;
}
add_filter('wpseo_json_ld_output', 'bybe_remove_yoast_json', 10, 1);
```

Comment: what do the 10,1 parameters do in the code?

Comment: See add_filter docs for Wordpress. They are: $priority
(int) (Optional) Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.

$accepted_args
(int) The number of arguments the function accepts.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the data Yoast produces is wrong, there is no harm in having it. Quite the contrary, having more structured data is better than having less.

If having it is "unnecessary" depends on your definition of what is necessary. Some consumers might be interested in it, others not.

My guess is that Yoast adds a `WebSite` entity because of Google’s [sitelinks searchbox](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/enhance-site#add-a-sitelinks-searchbox-for-your-site) rich snippet result, which allows Google users to search your site directly from the Google search result.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, John Mueller mentioned that the Organization type should not be added to every page: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-do-not-put-organization-schema-markup-on-every-page/289981/

Comment: @NicolasGuérinet: I disagree. Neither is he speaking for Schema.org, but for a consumer of Schema.org data; nor is he saying that it would be harmful to have an `Organization` item on every page. It’s a core feature of Schema.org that every `WebPage` item can have an `Organization` e.g. as `publisher`. It wouldn’t be helpful to provide the `publisher` only for one page, as it wouldn’t be clear then what the `publisher` for the other pages is -- there is nothing deceiving about providing it on every page. That said, the amount of provided data about the `Organization` might depend on the page.